# Plotly - Plot 2 Y Axes With Time Series

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to use r plotly to plot a chart that has following features:

1. Date objects as X-variable
2. 2 line plots in one charts with 2 Y-axis: one on the left, the other on the     right

   ```
   Date              Amount1          Amount2
   2/1/2017          19251130        21698.94
   2/2/2017          26429396        10687.37
   2/5/2017            669252            0.00
   2/6/2017          25944054        11885.10
   2/7/2017          27895562        14570.39
   2/8/2017          20842279        20080.56
   2/9/2017          25485527         9570.51
   2/10/2017          17008478        14847.49
   2/11/2017            172562            0.00
   2/12/2017            379397          900.00
   2/13/2017          25362794        18390.80
   2/14/2017          26740881        11490.94
   2/15/2017          20539413        22358.26
   2/16/2017          22589808        12450.45
   2/17/2017          18290862         3023.45
   2/19/2017           1047087          775.00
   2/20/2017           4159070         4100.00
   2/21/2017          28488401        22750.35
   ```

and the code I use is:

```
      ay <- list(
    #tickfont = list(color = "red"),
    overlaying = "y",
    side = "right"
  )

  p <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_lines(x = df$Date, y = df$Amount1, name = "Amount1",type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
    add_lines(x = df$Date, y = df$Amount2, name = "Amount2", yaxis = "y2",type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
    layout(
      title = "Chart Summary", yaxis2 = ay,
      xaxis = list(title="Date")
    )
```

[image: Chart]

The output chart looks fine but the date intervals on the X-axis is looking bad. I am wondering what is the solution to this, and if I want to have 2 histograms in one chart using the data above, what is the optimal way to do it?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `Date` column a `string` or `date`?

If it is a `string`, convert it to `date` and let Plotly take care of it.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date , "%m/%d/%Y")
```

---

[image: Autofix]
Full code

```
library('plotly')

txt <- "Date    Amount1 Amount2
2/1/2017    19251130    21698.94
2/2/2017    26429396    10687.37
2/5/2017    669252  0
2/6/2017    25944054    11885.1
2/7/2017    27895562    14570.39
2/8/2017    20842279    20080.56
2/9/2017    25485527    9570.51
2/10/2017   17008478    14847.49
2/11/2017   172562  0
2/12/2017   379397  900
2/13/2017   25362794    18390.8
2/14/2017   26740881    11490.94
2/15/2017   20539413    22358.26
2/16/2017   22589808    12450.45
2/17/2017   18290862    3023.45
2/19/2017   1047087 775
2/20/2017   4159070 4100
2/21/2017   28488401    22750.35"
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date , "%m/%d/%Y")
ay <- list(
  #tickfont = list(color = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right"
)

p <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(x = df$Date, y = df$Amount1, name = "Amount1",type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
  add_lines(x = df$Date, y = df$Amount2, name = "Amount2", yaxis = "y2",type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
  layout(
    title = "Chart Summary", yaxis2 = ay,
    xaxis = list(title="Date", ticks=df$Date)
  )
p
```

Comment: Thank you! That works.  I guess I missed <ticks=df$Date> so that the ticks on the x-axis is displaying incorrectly.